# Integer array to bitarray in c#

Tags: c#

I have an integer array of massive length. E.g. {2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, ....}.
I would like to convert this into an array of BitArrays in C#.
That is, 
010
011
100
010
100
010
001
100

So this can be changed into 3 BitArrays (bitarray of left most bit, bitarray of middle bit, bitarray of right most bit)

Problem here is that unlike bitset in java where you can directly store 0/1, bitarrays can only contain true/false. And since this array is extremely long, I do not want to use if/else, that is

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
   if (bit is 0) then  // time consuming step
       leftMostbitArray[0] = false;
   else
       leftMostbitArray[0] = true;
```

Is there any workaround where I could get rid of this step? Or probably a different datastructure. I would not like to use BitVector32 because of its size limitation.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Do you want to return one BitArray per integer, or just 3 BitArrays, one for each bit-position (assuming every integer is 0..7)?

Comment: Also, have you profiled your code, or are you just guessing that an if/else block will be slow?

Comment: @MichaelBray 3 bit arrays. So 1st bitarray will have leftmost bit of all the integer. from the above example leftMostBitArray should have 00101001. MiddleBitArray should have 11010100 and RightmostBitArray should have 01000010.

Comment: Instead of your if/else, you could do `leftMostbitArray[0] = (bit is 0)` (with the correct implementation of "bit is 0", of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4 };
BitArray b0 = new BitArray(a.Select(v => (v & (1 << 0)) != 0).ToArray());
BitArray b1 = new BitArray(a.Select(v => (v & (1 << 1)) != 0).ToArray());
BitArray b2 = new BitArray(a.Select(v => (v & (1 << 2)) != 0).ToArray());
```

The `b0` will have the "bit-position 0", or the right-most bit.  Then, `b1` and `b2` will have the next bit to the left, the next bit to the left, and so forth.  You could add more lines to get additional bits if needed - just keep adding one to the bit-shift parameter (`1 << #`).

Also I couldn't tell if you really cared about BitVector using true/false or not - there's no functional difference between this and storing 0/1.  If you *really* need to store 0/1 and you don't care about wasting memory, then you could use this syntax instead:

```
int[] vb0 = a.Select(v => (v & (1 << 0)) != 0 ? 1 : 0).ToArray()
...etc...
```